# Characterization of complex exponential in terms of real identities

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

It is well known (or at least easy to see) that the complex exponential function $\exp:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ can be charaterized as the unique holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}=1 \quad \text{and} \quad f(z+w)=f(z)f(w) \quad \text{for all } z,w\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
In fact we can make a stronger charaterization:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0,\; h\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}=1 \quad \text{and} \quad f(z+w)=f(z)f(w) \quad \text{for all } z,w\in\mathbb{C}.
$$

My question is: What are all the holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0,\; h\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}=1 \quad \text{and} \quad f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \quad \text{for all } x,y\in\mathbb{R}?
$$
Note the (perhaps big) difference: now the condition $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ is given for all **real** $x$ and $y$. I know that the complex exponential function is an example of such $f$, but are there any others? If not, how to prove that the exponential is the only function satisfying this conditions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the same: If $f$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$ with $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y\in \Bbb R$, then $f(z+w)=f(z)f(w)$ holds for all $z, w \in \Bbb C$, due to the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) for holomorphic functions.

- First fix $y\in \Bbb R$: Then $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ implies that $f(z+y)=f(z)f(y)$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.
- Now fix $z \in \Bbb C$: Then $f(z+y)=f(z)f(y)$ for all $y \in \Bbb R$ implies that $f(z+w)=f(z)f(w)$ for all $z, w \in \Bbb C$

Comment: how did you justify the first step?  Alternatively, you could say that on $\mathbb R$ you have $f'(x) = f(x)$  and $f'(0) = 1$ so $f$ must be $e^{x}$ for real $x$.  Now apply the identity theorem.

Comment: $f(z+y)$ and $f(z)f(y)$ are two entire functions which take the same values for $z = x \in \Bbb R$, i.e. on a set with accumulation point. Therefore they are identical.